# How to read a multidimensionnal javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, multidimensional-array, mustache

First of all, here is my Javascript object :

```
var languages = {
    languages: [
        { name: "French", locale: "FR", id: "-1" },
        { name: "English", locale: "IT", id: "-2" },
        { name: "Spanish", locale: "ES", id: "-3" },
        { name: "Zoulou", locale: "ZL", id: "-4" },
        { name: "Italian", locale: "EN", id: "-5" }
    ]
};
```

I'm using Mustache.js to generate language buttons:

```
function generateLanguages(languages) {
  var output = $("#languages-output");
  var template = "{{#languages}}<button id={{id}}><img src=#FLAG onclick='changeLanguage({{locale}})' /><p>{{name}}</p></button>{{/languages}}";
  html = Mustache.render(template, languages);
  output.append(html);}
```

I also have a folder containing all the flags images called `flags` (e.g flags/English.png).
**I'm trying to generate the buttons by adding the corresponding flag.**
I really have no idea how to do it, I thought to use the "locale" property of the Javascript object in a for loop and for each locale, create a big switch to choose the right image. If someone can help me ?

http://jsfiddle.net/lBrowz/7w5grype/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few improvements and ideas:

- Move templates to your HTML. That's where they should be. Reference them from JS by their ID. It's a lot easier to modify and think about templates when they are outside of the JavaScript.
- Maybe using flags for languages isn't the best choice. Sometimes a language cannot accurately be represented by a flag (see Zulu, which I chose to represent by the flag of Mozambique, but that might not be what your users expect. The same is true for English, when you think about it.)
- Anyway, instead of one flag image per language, use a single image that contains all flags and then use CSS sprites to display selected flags. I used this project here: http://tkrotoff.github.io/famfamfam_flags/
- Use `data-*` attributes to store extra information in elements.
- Use event delegation to handle clicks. **Never** use inline event handlers (like `onclick`).

```js
var languages = {
    languages: [
        { name: "French", locale: "FR", id: "-1", cls: "famfamfam-flag-fr" },
        { name: "English", locale: "IT", id: "-2", cls: "famfamfam-flag-gb" },
        { name: "Spanish", locale: "ES", id: "-3", cls: "famfamfam-flag-es" },
        { name: "Zoulou", locale: "ZL", id: "-4", cls: "famfamfam-flag-mz" },
        { name: "Italian", locale: "EN", id: "-5", cls: "famfamfam-flag-it" }
    ]
};

function changeLanguage(locale) {
    $("#locale").text(locale);
}

$(function () {
    var languagesTemplate = $("#languages-template").html();
    $("#languages-output").html( Mustache.render(languagesTemplate, languages) );

    $(document).on("click", ".language-button", function () {
        var locale = $(this).data("locale");
        changeLanguage(locale);
    });
});
```

```css
.language-button {
    width: 5em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: 3px;
}
.language-button > span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://tkrotoff.github.io/famfamfam_flags/famfamfam-flags.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="languages-output"></div>
<div id="locale"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="languages-template">
{{#languages}}
    <button id="{{id}}" class="language-button" data-locale="{{locale}}">
        <span class="{{cls}}"></span>
        <span>{{name}}</span>
    </button>
{{/languages}}
</script>
```

Run the code snippet above to see it live.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, I thought exactly to do that in the beginning but unfortunately, the JS object I receive comes from the database and there is no link with the images, for this reason I can't put anything related to the images into the JS object as you suggest me. I have to use the images folder in any case. So I think to do it in this way : I'll rename my images with the same name as the `name` of the object, and put` src = {{name}} `.

Comment: You don't have to use the images folder in any case, why would you think that? But of course you can, if you insist. The way you suggest is of course also possible.

Comment: Because I don't know how to show the right images without using as you said the JS object field `cls`. But it's ok, it's working now with the easy method ;) Thank you again !

Comment: @lBrowz Good to hear it works for you. (Don't forget to vote on the answer and mark it as accepted, too)